# Deleting some content from the text file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, text-files

I have text file called Load.txt which contains approximately 200 lines. I have a checkbox, If that is checked then I want to create a new file which had only first 100 lines from the Load.txt. And I am using c# for this program. Actually my real requirement is that I have to delete from line 110 to 201.And my code is below and because of some reason its deleting from line 1 to 92. I dnt know whats happening.

```
            String line = null;

            String tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            String filePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

            int line_number = 110;
            int lines_to_delete = 201;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
                {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        line_number++;

                        if (line_number <= lines_to_delete)
                            continue;

                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
```

So I figured out this issue. But my next issue is that: I am updating some of variables in the text file. Before my that code was alright . But now That code is conflicting with my delete lines code. If I am able to delete lines then I m not able to update those variables.

My Code is:

```
File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.File.ReadLine(sqlConnectionString).Take(110));
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, fileContents);
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: -1 for not bothering to Google such a simple question

Comment: Why are you reading a file name stored in `sqlConnectionString`?  Name your variables appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

```
File.WriteAllLines("new.txt", File.ReadLines("Load.txt").Take(100));
```

After update...

```
var desired = File.ReadLines("Load.txt")
                  .Take(110)  // "And I want to keep 1-110" -- OP
                  .Select(line => UpdateLine(line));  // "And I also want to update variables between 1-110" -- OP

File.WriteAllLines("new.txt", desired);

...

static string UpdateLine(string given)
{
     var updated = given;
     // other ops
     return updated;
}
```

[MSDN File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx)
[MSDN File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

Comment: Now your My code is not deleting the lines that I want to I mean after 110. But its able to update the variables after 110 line and not the one before 110. So I want to update variable from line 1-110 and delete all the lines after 110.

Comment: @JaspreetkaurDeol:  Your question states _I want to remove lines 110 thru 200_ but you state here that you want everything after line 110 deleted -- which is it?  How many lines are in "load.txt" and which lines to you want kept?

Comment: Okay, So I have a file that have 201 lines in load.txt. I want to delete lines from 110-201. And I also want to update variables between 1-110. And I want to keep 1-110.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I am updating variables like this in the file. doing something like this var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(SqlconnectionString); fileContents = fileContents.Replace("{param_1}", textBox1.Text.ToString()); I want to kinow how I can relate this to your updated Code. Sorry to bother you so much. Actually I new at C#

Comment: @JaspreetkaurDeol:  You'd put that code in the `UpdateLine` method.  You should just step through this code with a debugger and see if anything inspires you.

Answer (score 0):

THis should accomplish what you need. It reads the text then dumps 100 lines of it.

```
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("newLoad.txt", System.IO.File.ReadLines("Load.txt").Take(100));
```

Comment: Actually I replacing some content in text file also. Now my issue is that If I delete some lines from the text file then the rest of file doesn't get updated.

Comment: Here is the Code that's conflicting:                                                        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, fileContents);
File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName,System.IO.File.ReadLines(connectionString).Take(110));

Answer (score 0):

"I want to create a new file which had only first 100 lines"

Keeping with your original model, here's one way to keep just the first 100 lines:

```
        int LinesToKeep = 100;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                for (int i = 1; (i <= LinesToKeep) && ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null); i++)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

"my real requirement is that I have to delete from line 110 to 201"

So copy the file, but skip lines 110 to 201?

```
        int currentLine = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    currentLine++;
                    if (currentLine < 110 || currentLine > 201)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```